# Why doesn't my randomness check for random num gen work?

Tags: javascript, html

Some background information, this is a Rock Paper Scissor Spock and Lizard game with 2 players, human vs. ai. 
So far everything works and there is a table that allows you to see who wins but what I want is to how "random" my program really is. For example, I want to see the results of 100 plays and compare it to an ideal solution (evenly distributed 20/100 out of each variable [which in this case, has 5]).

**IMPORTANT!** Please keep in mind that the code I made should work in console, there is no visible table to check.

**Here is my code for the .js file and at the bottom is where the randomness check should be**

```
var Rock = document.getElementById('Rock').addEventListener('click', run);
var Paper = document.getElementById('Paper').addEventListener('click', run);
var Scissors = document.getElementById('Scissors').addEventListener('click', run);
var Lizard = document.getElementById('Lizard').addEventListener('click', run);
var Spock = document.getElementById('Spock').addEventListener('click', run);

var computerChoice;
var playerChoice;

var player = document.getElementById('player');
var computer = document.getElementById('computer');
var outcome = document.getElementById('outcome');

function run() {
    playerChoice = this.innerText;
    computerGamble();
    compare();
}
var playerChoice = 0
var computerChoice = 0

localStorage.setitem('win', '1')
localStorage.setitem('loss','2')

function computerGamble() {
    var dice = Math.random();
    if (dice <= 0.2) {
        computerChoice = "Rock";
    } else if (dice <= 0.4) {
        computerChoice = "Paper";
    } else if (dice <= 0.6) {
        computerChoice = "Scissors";
    } else if (dice <= 0.8) {
      computerChoice = "Lizard";
    } else{
      computerChoice = "Spock";
    }
}


 function compare() {
    player.innerHTML = "You have chosen " + playerChoice;
    computer.innerHTML = "Computer chooses " + computerChoice;

    if (playerChoice == computerChoice) {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Stalemate";

    } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Paper has trapped the rock, you lose!";
     counter.loss += 1;
    } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Rock has broken the scissors, you win!";
   counter.win += 1;

    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Rock has been trapped by paper, you win!";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Scissors snap the paper in half, you lose!";


    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Rock has broken the scissors, you lose!";
    } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
        outcome.innerHTML = "Scissor snaps the paper in half, you win!";

  } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && computerChoice === "Spock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Spock vaporizes rock, you lose!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Rock" && computerChoice === "Lizard") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Lizard gets knocked unconcious by rock, victory!";


  } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && computerChoice === "Spock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Spock has been disproved by paper, you win!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Paper" && computerChoice === "Lizard") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Lizard ate the paper, defeat!";


  } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && computerChoice === "Spock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Spock smashes scissors, you lose!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Scissors" && computerChoice === "Lizard") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Victory!";

  } else if (playerChoice === "Lizard" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Defeat!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Lizard" && computerChoice === "Spock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Victory!";


  } else if (playerChoice === "Lizard" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Victory!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Lizard" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Defeat!";


  } else if (playerChoice === "Spock" && computerChoice === "Paper") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Defeat!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Spock" && computerChoice === "Rock") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Victory!";

  } else if (playerChoice === "Spock" && computerChoice === "Lizard") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Defeat!";
  } else if (playerChoice === "Spock" && computerChoice === "Scissors") {
    outcome.innerHTML = "Victory!";

    }
 }
 function random(){
 total = 0;
 expected = 0;
 margin = 0;

 total = loop;
 loop = 0;
 expected = total * 0.2;
 margin = expected * 0.05;

     //player1 randomness start
     if(p1r == expected){
         console.log("Player1: rock is random");
         p1r = 0;
     }else{
         if(p1r == p1r - margin){
             console.log("Player1: rock is random");
             p1r = 0;
         }else{
             if(p1r == p1r + margin){
                 console.log("Player1: rock is random");
                 p1r = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("player1: rock is not random");
                 p1r = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p1p == expected){
         console.log("Player1: paper is random");
         p1p = 0;
     }else{
         if(p1p == p1p - margin){
             console.log("Player1: paper is random");
             p1p = 0;
         }else{
             if(p1p == p1p + margin){
                 console.log("Player1: paper is random");
                 p1p = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("player1: paper is not random");
                 p1p = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p1s == expected){
         console.log("Player1: scissor is random");
         p1s = 0;
     }else{
         if(p1s == p1s - margin){
             console.log("Player1: scissor is random");
             p1s = 0;
         }else{
             if(p1s == p1s + margin){
                 console.log("Player1: scissor is random");
                 p1s = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("player1: scissor is not random");
                 p1s = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p1l == expected){
         console.log("Player1: lizard is random");
         p1l = 0;
     }else{
         if(p1l == p1l - margin){
             console.log("Player1: lizard is random");
             p1l = 0;
         }else{
             if(p1l == p1l + margin){
                 console.log("Player1: lizard is random");
                 p1l = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("player1: lizard is not random");
                 p1l = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p1sp == expected){
         console.log("Player1: spock is random");
         p1sp = 0;
     }else{
         if(p1sp == p1sp - margin){
             console.log("Player1: spock is random");
             p1sp = 0;
         }else{
             if(p1sp == p1sp + margin){
                 console.log("Player1: spock is random");
                 p1sp = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("player1: spock is not random");
                 p1sp = 0;
             }
         }
     }
     //player1 ramdomness end

     //player2 randomness start
      if(p2r == expected){
         console.log("Player2: rock is random");
         p2r = 0;
     }else{
         if(p2r == p2r - margin){
             console.log("Player2: rock is random");
             p2r = 0;
         }else{
             if(p2r == p2r + margin){
                 console.log("Player2: rock is random");
                 p2r = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("Player2: rock is not random");
                 p2r = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p2p == expected){
         console.log("Player2: paper is random");
         p2p = 0;
     }else{
         if(p2p == p2p - margin){
             console.log("Player2: paper is random");
             p2p = 0;
         }else{
             if(p2p == p2p + margin){
                 console.log("Player2: paper is random");
                 p2p = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("Player2: paper is not random");
                 p2p = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p2s == expected){
         console.log("Player2: scissor is random");
         p2s = 0;
     }else{
         if(p2s == p2s - margin){
             console.log("Player2: scissor is random");
             p2s = 0;
         }else{
             if(p2s == p2s + margin){
                 console.log("Player2: scissor is random");
                 p2s = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("Player2: scissor is not random");
                 p2s = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p2l == expected){
         console.log("Player2: lizard is random");
         p2l = 0;
     }else{
         if(p2l == p2l - margin){
             console.log("Player2: lizard is random");
             p2l = 0;
         }else{
             if(p2l == p2l + margin){
                 console.log("Player2: lizard is random");
                 p2l = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("Player2: lizard is not random");
                 p2l = 0;
             }
         }
     }

     if(p2sp == expected){
         console.log("Player2: spock is random");
         p2sp = 0;
     }else{
         if(p2sp == p2sp - margin){
             console.log("Player2: spock is random");
             p2sp = 0;
         }else{
             if(p2sp == p2sp + margin){
                 console.log("Player2: spock is random");
                 p2sp = 0;
             }else{
                 console.log("Player2: spock is not random");
                 p2sp = 0;
             }
         }
     }
     //player2 ramdomness end
```

**Here is my code for the HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>RPSLS </title>
        <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
        <script>
            var p1r = 0;
            var p2r
            function onload(){
                document.getElementById('Rock').addEventListener('click', run);
                document.getElementById('Paper').addEventListener('click', run);
                document.getElementById('Scissors').addEventListener('click', run);
                document.getElementById('Lizard').addEventListener('click', run);
                document.getElementById('Spock').addEventListener('click', run);
            }

            function run() {
                var playerChoice = this.innerText;
                var computerChoice = rando(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]).value;

                document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = "You have chosen " + playerChoice;
                document.getElementById('computer').innerHTML = "Computer chooses " + computerChoice;

                if(playerChoice == computerChoice) {
                    //tie
                    document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = "Stalemate";
                    addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "tied");
                }
                else if(playerChoice == "Rock" && ["Spock", "Paper"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 ||
                    playerChoice == "Paper" && ["Scissors", "Lizard"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 ||
                    playerChoice == "Scissors" && ["Rock, Spock"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 ||
                    playerChoice == "Lizard" && ["Rock", "Scissors"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 ||
                    playerChoice == "Spock" && ["Paper", "Lizard"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1){
                    //player loses
                    document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = getActionPhrase([playerChoice, computerChoice]) + ", you lose!";
                    addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "lost");
                }
                else{
                    //player wins
                    document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = getActionPhrase([playerChoice, computerChoice]) + ", you win!";
                    addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "won");
                }
            }

            function getActionPhrase(choiceArray){
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1) return "Paper has trapped the rock";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1) return "Rock has broken the scissors";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Lizard gets knocked unconcious by rock";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock vaporizes rock";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1) return "Scissors snap the paper in half";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Lizard ate the paper";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock has been disproved by paper";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Scissors have decapitated the lizard";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock smashes the scissors";
                if(choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Lizard poisons Spock";
            }

            function addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, result){
                document.getElementById('record').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + playerChoice + "</td><td>" + computerChoice + "</td><td>" + result + "</td></tr>";
                var recordSpan = document.getElementById('record').getElementsByTagName('span')[["won", "lost", "tied"].indexOf(result)];
                recordSpan.innerHTML = Number(recordSpan.innerHTML) + 1;
            }
    </head>
    <body onload="onload();">
        <h1> RPSLS (RPSLS PROJECT) </h1>
        <h2>Rock, scissors, paper, lizard, spock, shake..!</h2>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/x5Q6-wMx-K8" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <div class="button-box">
            <button id="Rock">Rock</button>
            <button id="Paper">Paper</button>
            <button id="Scissors">Scissors</button>
            <button id="Lizard">Lizard</button>
            <button id="Spock">Spock</button>
        </div>
        <h5 id="player"></h5>
        <h5 id="computer"></h5>
        <h3 id="outcome"></h3>
        <table id="record">
            <tr>
                <td><span>0</span> = Your wins</td>
                <td><span>0</span> = Your losses</td>
                <td><span>0</span> = Your ties</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to test that randomly generated numbers between a range should equate to a percentage based on the quantity of numbers in the range? Apologies, but I am not clear what the question is.

Comment: No need to apologize, that is my fault for not explaining correctly. However, I believe you are correct. Basically, after 100 runs of the simulation I want to find out the percentage exact percentage of the variables that were chosen out of a 100 and compare it to the ideal "equal" value which is 20/100. It does not necessarily have to compare it because anyone with a calculator could do it.

Comment: There is way to much code here, all kinds of unrelated stuff like a form to send emails etc.Please make a **minimal** example and use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)  Also please fix your syntax errors which wil show up in the JavaScript console.

Comment: Alright, no idea how to use a snippet but I will trim the lines code that are primarily for aesthetics.

Comment: @gman Could you please check to see if this is applicable? Thank you!

Comment: if anyone is interested in seeing the website and the entire code it can be found here on github; https://github.com/umaruf-tech/rpsls and https://umaruf-tech.github.io/rpsls/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated HTML file that will log in the console whether the computer/player picks were within the expected margin each time a round is played. I commented out the HTML table that shows up on the actual page because I think this is what you want instead of that. Feel free to uncomment it if you still want it. To be very clear, the only 2 files you need are this one and your CSS file. Name this one anything you want, but make sure the file extension is ".html". Then name your CSS file "theme.css", and place it in the same folder you put this HTML file in. Then you should be golden.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>RPSLS </title>
            <script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
            <link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script>
                function onload(){
                    document.getElementById('Rock').addEventListener('click', run);
                    document.getElementById('Paper').addEventListener('click', run);
                    document.getElementById('Scissors').addEventListener('click', run);
                    document.getElementById('Lizard').addEventListener('click', run);
                    document.getElementById('Spock').addEventListener('click', run);
                }

                function run() {
                    var playerChoice = this.innerText;
                    var computerChoice = rando(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]).value;

                    document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = "You have chosen " + playerChoice;
                    document.getElementById('computer').innerHTML = "Computer chooses " + computerChoice;

                    if(playerChoice == computerChoice) {
                        //tie
                        document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = "Stalemate";
                        addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "tied");
                    }
                    else if(playerChoice == "Rock" && ["Spock", "Paper"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 || 
                        playerChoice == "Paper" && ["Scissors", "Lizard"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 || 
                        playerChoice == "Scissors" && ["Rock, Spock"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 || 
                        playerChoice == "Lizard" && ["Rock", "Scissors"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1 || 
                        playerChoice == "Spock" && ["Paper", "Lizard"].indexOf(computerChoice) > -1){
                        //player loses
                        document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = getActionPhrase([playerChoice, computerChoice]) + ", you lose!";
                        addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "lost");
                    }
                    else{
                        //player wins
                        document.getElementById('outcome').innerHTML = getActionPhrase([playerChoice, computerChoice]) + ", you win!";
                        addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, "won");
                    }
                }

                function getActionPhrase(choiceArray){
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1) return "Paper has trapped the rock";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1) return "Rock has broken the scissors";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Lizard gets knocked unconcious by rock";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Rock") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock vaporizes rock";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1) return "Scissors snap the paper in half";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Lizard ate the paper";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Paper") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock has been disproved by paper";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1) return "Scissors have decapitated the lizard";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Scissors") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Spock smashes the scissors";
                    if(choiceArray.indexOf("Lizard") > -1 && choiceArray.indexOf("Spock") > -1) return "Lizard poisons Spock";
                }

                var roundsPlayed = 0;
                var computerPlayed = {
                    Rock: 0,
                    Paper: 0, 
                    Scissors: 0, 
                    Lizard: 0, 
                    Spock: 0
                };
                var playerPlayed = {
                    Rock: 0,
                    Paper: 0, 
                    Scissors: 0, 
                    Lizard: 0, 
                    Spock: 0
                };
                function addToRecord(playerChoice, computerChoice, result){
                    var expected = .2;
                    var margin = 0.05;
                    console.log("\n\nROUND " + (roundsPlayed + 1) + ":");
                    if(++computerPlayed[computerChoice] / ++roundsPlayed >= expected - margin && computerPlayed[computerChoice] / roundsPlayed <= expected + margin){
                        console.log("Computer played " + computerChoice + " within our expected margin.");
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Computer played " + computerChoice + " OUTSIDE OF our expected margin.");
                    }

                    if(++playerPlayed[playerChoice] / roundsPlayed >= expected - margin && playerPlayed[playerChoice] / roundsPlayed <= expected + margin){
                        console.log("Player played " + playerChoice + " within our expected margin.");
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Player played " + playerChoice + " OUTSIDE OF our expected margin.");
                    }

                    document.getElementById('record').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + playerChoice + "</td><td>" + computerChoice + "</td><td>" + result + "</td></tr>";
                    var recordSpan = document.getElementById('record').getElementsByTagName('span')[["won", "lost", "tied"].indexOf(result)];
                    recordSpan.innerHTML = Number(recordSpan.innerHTML) + 1;
                }
            </script>
            <style>
                #record{
                    margin:auto;
                    border-collapse:collapse;
                }

                #record td{
                    padding:5px 10px;
                }

                #record tbody:first-of-type td{
                    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="onload();">
            <h1> For Mrs. Romero (RPSLS PROJECT) </h1>
            <h2>Rock, scissors, paper, lizard, spock, shake..!</h2>
            <div class="button-box">
                <button id="Rock">Rock</button>
                <button id="Paper">Paper</button>
                <button id="Scissors">Scissors</button>
                <button id="Lizard">Lizard</button>
                <button id="Spock">Spock</button>
            </div>
            <h5 id="player"></h5>
            <h5 id="computer"></h5>
            <h3 id="outcome"></h3>
            <table id="record">
                <tr>
                    <td><span>0</span> wins.</td>
                    <td><span>0</span> losses.</td>
                    <td><span>0</span> ties.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

This file requires you to physically pick a hand to play each round and get results in the console. If you don't feel like doing that 100 times, you can optionally just run this in the console of the opened HTML file to simulate 100 picks:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    document.getElementById(rando(["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors", "Lizard", "Spock"]).value).click()
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: As always, wonderful assistance from you Mr. Plocharczyk. However, how come the .js file is not needed?

Comment: Also, the table is still useful and when I try to do as you say (one index.html file in a folder with the theme.css file) I can't see the check for randomness anywhere and in the console when I put in the second line of code in console it only selects one variable

Comment: Hey, so far I have tried everything and it still does not work

Comment: We don't need the JS file because I've written the javascript within the script tag in this HTML file. I'll uncomment the table in my answer for you. Just to be clear, you've copied the first block of code, saved it as an HTML file, placed it in a folder with your theme.css file, opened the HTML file, right click>inspect>console, and then pasted the second block of code into the console and pressed enter?

Comment: Thank you again! The mistake was that I had two .js files and I was putting the wrong code in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any random number generation in your example so have included a simple function that will generate a random number between to int's.

There is an example to generate 100 random numbers and check that they are within your expected target percentage:

```js
// generate random number - min and max are inclusive
function getRandom(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

// 5 options
const options = 5;
const results = [];
for (let i = 0; i < options; i++) {
  results[i] = 0;
}

// generate 100 random numbers and record the result
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let random = getRandom(1, options);
  results[random - 1]++;
}

// output the results
console.log(results);
console.log(results.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue));
```

Comment: How would I access the outputs? In the console?

Comment: To log to the console you use `console.log()` - see the example that logs the output to the console

Comment: it's in his html file within the script tag. it uses randojs.com for randomness. notice the call to rando()

Comment: Ah, missed that - far too much code to process for an opinion question. ;-)